# ElasticSearch - No Hits using NEST Client, but underlying query in Kibana dev tools returns hits

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I'm setting up some integration tests for an ElasticSearch function but getting unexpected behaviour - No hits are returned by the NEST search, but the underlying query works fine when copied into kibana dev tools and I can't see why.

Interestingly, the same search running on an index in our dev environment with *real* documents, does return results so I suspect it may be something to do with typing, although the mappings on the *real* and test indices are the same.

- **NEST Client**: 7.17.1 (latest at the time of writing)
- **ES instance version**: 8.1.2

The Client setup, indexing snippet and model in the test classes mirror those used in the production code.

**ElasticClient Setup and indexing snippet** *edited to include code for adding documents to the index*

```
            var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
                .DefaultIndex(TestIndexName)
                .DisableDirectStreaming()
                .EnableApiVersioningHeader()
                .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);

            ElasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

            ElasticClient
                .Indices
                .Create(TestIndexName, c=> 
                    c.Map<ElasticPage>(m=>m.AutoMap()));

            var bulkIndexResponse = ElasticClient
                .Bulk(b => b.Index(TestIndexName)
                    .IndexMany(content)
                    .Pipeline("html_strip"));
```

**ElasticPage Model**

```
    public class ElasticPage
    {
        [Text(Name = "intro")]
        public string Intro { get; set; }
        [Text(Name = "subTitle")]
        public string SubTitle { get; set; }
        [Text(Name = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Keyword(Name = "path")]
        public string Path { get; set; }
        [Text(Name = "textProperties")]
        public string[] TextProperties { get; set; }
    }
```

**Search Snippet**

```
        var searchResults = await _fixture.ElasticClient
            .SearchAsync<ElasticPage>(s => s
                .Index(_fixture.TestIndexName)
                .Query(q=>
                    q.MatchAll()));
```

**Sample Debug Information**

```
Valid NEST response built from a successful (200) low level call on POST: /a601cc24-ecbc-4e25-a582-dcd8da9e5cfb/_search?typed_keys=true
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: {REDACTED} Took: 00:00:00.1089519
# Request:
{"query":{"match_all":{}}}
# Response:
{"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":0,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

**Query I run in kibana based on the Debug Information**

```
POST /a601cc24-ecbc-4e25-a582-dcd8da9e5cfb/_search?typed_keys=true
{"query":{"match_all":{}}}
```

**Kibana Results**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "a601cc24-ecbc-4e25-a582-dcd8da9e5cfb",
        "_id" : "RKhtrYAB2MIpGr4Mtcii",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "path" : "/home-page",
          "subTitle" : "home page",
          "textProperties" : [
            "Section 1  with some html ",
            "Section 2"
          ],
          "intro" : "intro text",
          "title" : "home-page"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Edit** switching the search document type to *dynamic* also results in no hits

```
 var searchResults = await _fixture.ElasticClient
            .SearchAsync<dynamic>(s => s
                .Index(_fixture.TestIndexName)
                .Query(q=>
                    q.MatchAll()));
```

Comment: How do you index documents for test? Do you refresh index after indexing documents so they are available for search?

Comment: yes - after creating the index I deserialise a bunch of JSON files into `ElasticPage` objects and then Bulk add them to the index - I will add the code snippet for that above.

Comment: @Rob - I re-read what you said, and you were bang-on - the index wasn't being refreshed manually, so while it was being refreshed after a few seconds, the test was running before it was ready.

`ElasticClient.Indices.Refresh();` after the bulk index seems to have fixed it.

If you'd like to put that as an answer, I will happily upvote and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Indexed documents are not available for search immediately, elasticsearch needs to handle [refresh operation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) first so probably test is indexing documents and doing search right away.

That can be fixed by specifying [refresh parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-refresh) when doing bulk index.

```
var bulkAllObservable = client.BulkAll(people, b => b
    .Index("people")
    .BackOffTime("30s") 
    .BackOffRetries(2) 
    .RefreshOnCompleted()
    .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
    .Size(1000) 
)
.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), next => 
{
    // do something e.g. write number of pages to console
});
```

This code sample comes from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/indexing-documents.html#bulkall-observable